# How to bend object A the way object B is bent?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

Few days I am having a problem to understand how one logo is created.

I tried recreating it in Illustrator and Photoshop, but I failed.

This is the logo

[image]

What gives me a problem is how to get down part, bent rectangle shapes.
We have a "Nike like" shape on T, and under it we have exactly the same bent rectangles grid.

I can create all until it comes to the rectangles grid, also I can create a shape that is bent on the same way.

[image]

I have tried creating grid of rectangles and then warping it next to "Nike like" shape at the bottom of letter T, I get close, but it is not perfect, it has to be perfect, it is perfect on logo, someone made it, there has to be a way.

So, I am thinking.

1. "Nike like part" and rectangles grid was a part of a same "tube like" shape that is somehow manipulated into this look. (I suspect this is the case, but it could be.)
2. T and "Nike like shape" is created first, then a grid of rectangles is manipulated to sit exactly bent as the "Nike like shape" is.
3. "Nike like shape" is copied into two instances, blended, and they got like I did in the upper image, and then somehow they manipulated this shape into grid.

In any scenario, I am not sure what to do.

The biggest problem to match rectangle grid shape to "Nike like" bent shape in Illustrator is that I can not get a complete path around so I can match the bending with Anchor Point Tool.

[image]

As you can see, every rectangle has it's own path, and no matter what I tried, compound path, expand, export as png, then image trace, group, blend - expand, unite with pathfinder (colors mix - so it is wrong), merge with pathfinder (different color still have it is own part - it does nothing in the end).

So, yeah, this is a big problem for me, so if someone has idea how this is done, I would appreciate some help. It does not matter, Illustrator or Photoshop.

Comment: Isolate the edge curves and use a blend between opposite curves. Thinking bend 3D in a application that has just 2 dimensions is a random endeavor at best. By the way your bend does not have perspective contraction like the original

Answer (score 2):

Guessing automatically the needed bending is beyond the capabilities of the common graphics software. I show how to get the 3D appearance with Envelope distortion. Mapping the planar original on a 3D model would create the geometrically valid view with no effort, but a proper 3D model should be made at first. And the model should be just the one of the infinite number of possibilities which as 2D rendering gives the wanted projected view of the dots. Not recommended!

3D perspective is not the cause of the downwards shrinking of the white dots. They are made in the beginning to have different sizes, as you have tried, too. In the next (Illustrator) image the dot pattern is made by blending. It has the right number of dots, but their places and sizes are only somewhat reminiscent. The top row and the white row are made at first separately and then the rows are expanded and blended:

[image]

In the middle the dots have got white fill and they are grouped with an underlying purple rectangle.

In the right the group is distorted by applying Envelope Distortion. That method is valid for all images, not only for a pattern of rectangular dots. It got Object > Envelope Distortion > Make with mesh > 1 x 1 mesh. More mesh rows and columns in theory give more control, but even an 1x1 mesh has in the corners total 8 handles which all must be adjusted right with the white arrow.

Fortunately the result can still be edited until it's in accordance with the wanted illusion of the 3D bending.

The purple rectangle is only for visualization the exact edges. It can be removed after expanding the envelope distortion or it can be made colorless even inside the envelope.

In the next image my version is placed on your screenshot and the envelope is adjusted to fit. The sharpness and slightly wrong color reveal it's an implant:

[image]

A need to distort a rectangle or a pattern which is inside a rectangle to fit an existing non-rectangular reference shape is common. Adjusting the envelope is much easier if the reference shape is rotated at first so that one edge of the distorted pattern can be vertical or horizontal (if possible) and before inserting the envelope distortion the pattern is scaled to nearly right final dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to recreate the logo exactly, or as near as possible to the orginal, then I would try a different approach.  One thing I would say however is that the original is not perfect. The squares in the grid look ever so slightly wonky, but it is what it is I suppose!

Draw some curved lines with the Pen tool to match the squares on the grid and use the shape builder tool to make the pieces.

For example

[image]

It would also be possible to make a more regular grid using blends, and then distort with an envelope mesh. But I don't honestly know if it's really any better. It's still somewhat wonky to be honest.

For example

[image]

Comment: They are vonly because although they have an apparent perspective in one direction but tey dont have the perspective in the other.

Comment: @joojaa yeah. It just doesn't look good IMHO.  A logo in dire need of improvement I think.